# How to print if match present and leave if not with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a result file `A.tsv` (separator = `\t`):

```
BC01    2551    99
BC03    2547    95
BC04    2578    99
BC05    2547    97
```

And a file with sample information `B.tsv` (separator = `\t`):

```
BC01
BC04
BC02
BC03
BC05
```

And I want to add to `A.tsv` (but print in a new file) the sample that are missing from `B.tsv`:

```
BC01    2551    99
BC02
BC03    2547    95
BC04    2578    99
BC05    2547    97
```

So far I've try some awk command but nothing concluant :

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{print $0};NR!=FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{print $1}' B.tsv A.tsv > C.tsv
```

Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A right approach to process these files would be decode `A.tsv` into an dictionary keyed by `$1`, storing the contents of whole line and then using it later on `B.tsv` to lookup the values i.e.

```bsh
awk -v FS="\t" ' FNR == NR { arr[$1] = $0; next } 
  ( $1 in arr ){ print arr[$1]; next } { print $1 }' A.tsv B.tsv
```

If you want the final result sorted by `$1`, then you might need to index contents on both files and process it finally in the `END` by printing the key alone if value is not present

```bsh
awk -v FS="\t" ' FNR == NR { arr[$1] = $0; next } 
  !( $1 in arr ) { arr[$1] } END { for (x in arr) print arr[x] ? arr[x] : x }' A.tsv B.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly !